# Cannot get/ heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, heroku

[Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YekB.png)

I uploaded my project to heroku and at first it seemed like everything worked out, the home page loads normal but when I try to access the following pages it just gives me a Cannot get/

[/alunos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FtGp.png)

```
const Routes: React.FC = () => {
    return(
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
            <Route path='/alunos' exact component={Alunos} />
            <Route path='/cadastro_aluno' exact component={AlunosForm} />
            <Route path='/tarefas_cadastro/:id' exact component={AlunosForm} />
            <Route path='/alunos/:id' exact component={AlunosDetail} />
            <Route path='/loc' exact component={AlunosLoc} />
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default Routes;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3102
 
app.use(express.static('build'))
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Servidor Front em execução!'))
```

[f12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlfQw.png)

Comment: Hmm, you are using typescript I guess. You can tag your question with typescript also. The problem might be with that `React.FC = () => {`  part. You should also wrap your routing code with `<Router></Router>` tag. The diagram should be like: return-router-div-switch-route.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Navbar.Brand href="/">Home</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="me-auto">
        <Nav.Link as = {Link} to="/alunos">Alunos</Nav.Link>          
        <NavDropdown title="Mais" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
```

I  made some changes to the header, added the import Link and made the links for it ( as = {Link}), thanks everyone for the help